# Continually getting this error with my SQL code

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, authentication

Error says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
```

My query:

```
CREATE TABLE `login`.`login`(
`id` SERIAL NOT NULL,
`user` VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
`pass` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE(
`user`,
`pass`
)
```

Comment: Do you need a `;` at the end?

Comment: Are you missing a ')' bracket at the end?

Comment: `SERIAL` is for `pgsql` but not `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
CREATE TABLE `login`(
`id` INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`user` VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
`pass` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE(`user`,`pass`)
)
```